# how to query istio metadata exchange data in envoy access log?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I know with the latest istio version, it start to integrate the `metadata-exchange` extension to envoy proxy, so that when communicate between each pod, envoy will potential use the "x-envoy-peer-metadata" header to exchange the pod metadata and save in metadata exchange extension cache.

So my questions is,

1. Is there a way that I can list the existing data in this `metadata-exchange` extension cache?
2. I know envoy proxy support `DYNAMIC_METADATA` in its access log format, is it related with the `metadata-exchange` extension?
3. Finally, how can I query the metadata in extension and log it in envoy access log. Such as, besides the `DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS`, also i wish to output the `downstream pod name`.